# add ordering number to specific text

Tags: bash, text-processing, perl

Is there any way to add a number into a specific text?
On my text file:

```
<a href="http://localhost/file1.txt">file </a>
<a href="http://localhost/file2.txt">file </a>

<a href="http://localhost/file1.txt">file </a>
<a href="http://localhost/file2.txt">file </a>
<a href="http://localhost/file2.txt">file </a>

<a href="http://localhost/file.1.txt">file </a>
<a href="http://localhost/file.2.txt">file </a>
<a href="http://localhost/file.3.txt">file </a>
<a href="http://localhost/file.4.txt">file </a>
```

and add ordering number to the file and the output:

```
<a href="http://localhost/file1.txt">file 1</a>
<a href="http://localhost/file2.txt">file 2</a>

<a href="http://localhost/file1.txt">file 1</a>
<a href="http://localhost/file2.txt">file 2</a>
<a href="http://localhost/file2.txt">file 3</a>

<a href="http://localhost/file1.txt">file 1</a>
<a href="http://localhost/file2.txt">file 2</a>
<a href="http://localhost/file3.txt">file 3</a>
<a href="http://localhost/file4.txt">file 4</a>
```

Comment: Is the fifth non-empty line supposed to link to `file.2` as well, or is that a typo?

Comment: The criterium to follow is ambiguous here. Do you want to progressively number the text of the links starting again from 1 after each empty line? Or do you want to change the text of the links based on the filename following a criterium (which seems to be to drop the extension and to add a space before an (I guess optional) number at the end)?

Comment: Or better, please phrase exactly what the criterium should be, for example explaining how you would do it by hand. We can easily make an hard-coded solution for your example, but it might not work on your real file. Or provide an example of the real file.

Comment: @kos i want it start again from number 1 after each empty line

Comment: This question got a lot better. It might be harder to handle now, but it it's also more interesting.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's|\([^.e]*\).txt">.... |&\1|' <in >out
```

And... you simplified it again.

And... complicated it again. So the above will just copy numbers that are already in the string - it doesn't fix any broken ones. This will:

```
{  sed '/./!G;s/\n/::::::&::::/
        s/\(.*[^0-9]\)[0-9][^.]*/\1  /' |
   nl   -d::|
   sed 's/ *\([0-9]*\)\(.*\)  \(.*\) /\2\1\3 \1/'
}  <infile >outfile
```

That uses `nl`'s logical page separator to count only the *sections* as delimited by blank lines. It is *a lot* more involved than the first one, though.

I expanded it a little to handle fairly arbitrary *(!single-line!)* file-names.

Comment: sorry @mikeserv i've edited my question

Comment: @juicebyah - i dont get it - you need to make it clearer. What about *data* lines - those should go away and they should just all say *file* regardless

Comment: sorry forgot to edit all , i've fixed it again ,

Comment: Your `sed` command does not seem to create the specified output from the given input.

Comment: @Janis - Good point. I've got an extra space now. The input has moved around on me a little bit, to be fair though. I just need to remove it - thank you.

Comment: @mikeserv; Still, it produces wrong results. - Inspect the duplicate "file 2" in the second block and the complete failure on the third data block.

Comment: @juicebyah - so what's the deal - do we sometimes have extra dots or never? Is it sometimes *.1.txt* or is it always *e1.txt*?

Comment: @Janis - that just changed a minute ago - but why should dup2 change at all?

Comment: @Janis - anyway the 3rd block is fixed - but I dunno what you mean by the 2 thing.

Comment: @mikeserv; I understand the OP that he wants a consistent final numbering, as indicated in his "output".

Comment: @mikeserv this piece of code worked like a charm. thank you!

Comment: how about if we would like to use for <a href="http://localhost.com/file/movie/mytitle/how.to.do.E20.450p-randomname.avi">Episodes </a> , with a random name in each avi file

Comment: @juicebyah - well, I just did another edit, and, I think this way it should just flat work with any filename - except that there can only be one numeric string within the filename, and it *must* be the one you want to replace.

Comment: it doesnt work for source file http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/20NY@mikeserv ,  this is the output what i got http://pasted.co/b8b4c479

Comment: @juicebyah - where did E01 come from? I'll make another edit that will fix this, but I'm not going to do 100 different things here, you know. 1 question = 1 answer - yeah? Hey - I told you it can only have the 1 number - that's why it breaks - how can I know where to put it otherwise?

Comment: sorry my bad , i wasnt clear enought from my previous question

Comment: @juicebyah - don't sweat it. I hope the above will help. Note that it now relies on the *[number]* which needs to addressing as being the *last* in in the input string. So there won't be any issues with numbers or whatever in the filenames or url, but you have to mean to change the last one.

Comment: @juicebyah - does it work for you?

Comment: its not working , i use sed 's|\([^.e]*\).avi">Episodes |&\1|' <in >out and the output was Episodes Episodes l , and the second sed doesnt change anything.

Comment: @juicebyah - oh yeah, it doesn't do anything because you don't feed it anything. I forgot to show `<in` `>out` for that - you need to give it an infile. Could that be it? I tested it with your paste and it did like:      *`<a href="http://localhost.com/1256bbbax/series/titles/grey.anatomy.E1.somerandomtext.avi">Episodes 1l</a>
 <a href="http://localhost.com/1256bbbax/series/titles/grey.anatomy.E2.somerandomtext.avi">Episodes 2l</a>`* - there's that extra *`l`* there, but that was on input, too.

Comment: this is what i did : sed 's|\([^.e]*\).avi">Episodes |&\1|' a.txt and the output is : <a href="http://localhost.com/1256bbbax/series/titles/grey.anatomy.E1.somerandomtext.avi">Episodes xt</a>

Comment: @juicebyah - don't use the top one for those - it won't work. That only works with the sample provided. You have to use the bottom pipeline.

Comment: yes @mikeserv it works with the new code on the bottom. thanks a lot for your help mate :D

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk '
  !NF { c=0 ; print ; next }
  { sub(/file.*txt/,"file"++c".txt")
    sub(/>file </,">file "c"<")
    print
  }
'
```

Comment: Granted, the question is unclear; but I see nothing in the Q to warrant changing the number in the filename in the `href=` string (e.g., on line 6 (the fifth non-blank line).

Comment: solution provide by @janis also could be use, thank you!

Comment: how about if we would like to use for <a href="http://localhost.com/file/movie/mytitle/how.to.do.E20.450p-randomname.avi">Episodes </a> , with a random name in each avi file

Comment: @G-Man; Yes, the question is not perfectly clear. The choosen names, though, suggest that a "file 3" text shall be associated with a "file3.txt" object. If that's not the case the OP will clarify.